# Can I get source code which I upload on Azure server?

Tags: azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I deployed my sql base on Azure with Entity Framework. But now i lost my source code. Host still working. How can I download it form Azure server?

Comment: Where did you deploy

Comment: On Microsoft Azure via Visual Studio

Comment: no i am asking about which compute? vm or appservice or what

Comment: On Win 10 without wm, but I reuinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

For this need download FileZilla and do what wrote there:
[https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f#:~:text=Just%20expand%20the%20%E2%80%9Csite%E2%80%9D%20directory,project%20back%20in%20your%20possession](https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f#:%7E:text=Just%20expand%20the%20%E2%80%9Csite%E2%80%9D%20directory,project%20back%20in%20your%20possession).